# Is it possible to recover an ISO image from a balenaEtcher flashed drive?

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive, iso-image, flash

First of all, I might have no choice in this matter anyway. Recently I flashed an OEM Windows image onto a flash drive using balenaEtcher. This drive is not bootable currently and I suspect it's due to balena not being able to flash Windows images.

EDIT: Seems like my initial thought was correct. According to [balenaEcher Documentation](https://github.com/balena-io/etcher/blob/master/docs/USER-DOCUMENTATION.md?d_id=92e06341-01fc-4a38-a96b-16e28fc39aa8&s_id=1672837261619#why-is-my-drive-not-bootable&d_id=cd487682-a89e-4ed8-ab44-4db39c92db4a&s_id=1689409469848) they don't support Windows images and recommend tools like Rufus.

Next, I would like to recover the flashed ISO as I no longer have access to the origin ISO flashed to the drive using balenaEtcher. Is this even possible?

For curiosity's sake would this be possible if I flashed a supported image, i.e. Ubuntu installation to the flash drive and would like to recover that ISO?

Comment: Please read my comment under the answer. It's NO, absolutely NOT, end of the story.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is software to create an ISO file but as the ISO contains a system area of 32768 bytes that is unused you may experience a surprise when creating an ISO file out of the content of a CD, DVD or a USB flash drive.

I wrote an ISO file to a DVD and read it back into another ISO file and compared the files using a checksum generator. The files had differences which seems to be due to the handling of the system area. I guess sometimes the empty area is part of the ISO file, sometimes not.

Comment: The only answer for the question that actually matters to the author is a rotund NO. And it has nothing to do with what you ramble about here but because Microsoft ISOs since years ago don't respect the format standards therefore can't be "burned" with `dd` which is what Etcher and almost everything similar uses under the hood (also Rufus but not the default method). *Ergo*, although you can make an ISO from whatever was written to the USB drive it'll have ZERO practical usage.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, I'm afraid you have it the other way around. It's Linux ISOs that are **abusing** the ISO-9660 standard to enable `dd` "burning", through a hack called [ISOHybrid](https://wiki.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=Isohybrid). If you take Linux ISOs published 10-15 years ago, you will find that they cannot be written using `dd` on account that ISOHybrid is a relatively modern feature (and though in most case it works great, it is not always a panacea). So, in this case, Microsoft __does__ respect the UDF or ISO-9660 format standards to the letter, and it's Linux distros that don't.

Comment: Also, if OP only plans to boot UEFI hardware only, then creating an ISO from the USB will work just as well as having the original ISO, since UEFI boot is file system based (as opposed to sector based for BIOS) and almost every UEFI bootloader out there is designed for both HDD/SSD and optical boot. So if you create an ISO from the USB files, the UEFI bootloader file will be copied over, and the resulting ISO will be detected and usable as bootable because it includes the UEFI bootloaders. However, media validation through checksums may fail as pointed out above.

Comment: Akeo, based on the knowledge required to develop and improve Rufus I give you credit and I would like you to post your findings as a full answer.
Feel invited to downvote my post, I can't do it. I don't want to delete my answer which seems to be questionable according to ChanganAuto, because your answers would disappear as well!